# SELECT from Union x 3 using filter of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

#### Background

I have a web application which must remove entries from other tables, filtered through a selection of 'tielists' from table 1 -> item_table 1, table 2, table 3.... now basically my result set is going to be filthy big unless I use a filter statement from another table, using a user_id...  so can someone please help me structure my statement as needed? TY!

#### Tables

```
cars_belonging_to_user
-----------------------------
ID | user_id | make   | model
----------------------------
1  |  1      | Toyota | Camry
2  |  1      |Infinity| Q55
3  |  1      | DMC    | DeLorean
4  |  2      | Acura  | RSX

Okay, Now the three 'tielists'
name:tielist_one
----------------------------
id | id_of_car | id_x | id_y|
1  | 1         | 12   | 22  |
2  | 2         | 23   | 32  |
-----------------------------
name:tielist_two
-------------------------------
id | id_of_car | id_x | id_z|
1  |  3        | 32   | 22  |
-----------------------------
name: tielist_three
id | id_of_car | id_x | id_a|
 1 | 4         | 45   | 2   |
------------------------------
```

#### Result Set and Code

```
echo name_of_tielist_table
// I can structure if statements to echo result sets based upon the name
// Future Methodology: if car_id is in tielist_one, delete id_x from x_table, delete id_y from y_table...
// My output should be a double select base:
--SELECT * tielists from WHERE car_id is 1... output name of tielist... then
--SELECT * from specific_tielist where car_id is 1.....delete x_table, delete y_table...
```

Considering the list will be massive, and the tielist equally long, I must filter the results where `car_id(id) = $variable && user_id = $id....`

#### Side Notes

1. Only one car id will appear once in any single tielist..
2. This select statement MUST be filtered with user_id = $variable... (and remember, i'm looking for which car id too)
3. I MUST HAVE THE NAME of the tielist it comes from able to be echo'd into a variable...
4. I will only be looking for one single `id_of_car` at any given time, because this select will be contained in a foreach loop.
5. I was thinking a `union all` items would do the trick to select the row, but how can I get the name of the tielist the row is in, and how can the filter be used from the user_id row

Comment: Why, why oh why do you have all these separate `tielist_*` tables and not a single table with a column that identifies their differences?  Having tables with identical schema is usually a sign of very poor design.

Comment: @eggyal tell me about it... when I came onto the project I almost balled my eyes out and scratched at walls when I finally found out how poorly the original design had been made...  It would be a breach of my contract to fully delve **WHY** this must be done, but... i'm not about to rebuild the wheel for what they are paying me.  :-(  its still alpha version, and against what i've recommended, they still wanna do what they wanna do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want performance, I would suggest `left outer join` instead of `union all`.  This will allow the query to make efficient use of indexes for your purpose.

Based on what you say, a car is in exactly one of the lists.  This is important for this method to work.  Here is the SQL:

```
select cu.*,
       coalesce(tl1.id_x, tl2.id_x, tl3.id_x) as id_x,
       tl1.y, tl2.idz, tl3.id_a,
       (case when tl1.id is not null then 'One'
             when tl2.id is not null then 'Two'
             when tl3.id is not null then 'Three'
        end) as TieList
from Cars_Belonging_To_User cu left ouer join
     TieList_One tl1
     on cu.id_of_car = tl1.id_of_car left outer join
     TieList_Two tl2
     on cu.id_of_car = tl2.id_of_car left outer join
     TieList_Three tl3
     on cu.id_of_car = tl3.id_of_car;
```

You can then add a `where` clause to filter as you need.

If you have an index on `id_of_car` for each tielist table, then the performance should be quite good.  If the `where` clause uses an index on the first table, then the joins and where should all be using indexes, and the query will be quite fast.

Comment: @hawkhorrow . . . That is what the column `TieList` tells you.

Comment: @hawkhorrow . . . You want an index on `id_of_car`.

Comment: hahaha  sounded like an epic facepalmable question...im just building an index for the first time through phpmyadmin, and obviously extra options available for that one, so i guess i stepped in the poo before actually clearing up that it was my first time building a special index lmao....last time i tried i needed a full db rebuild, so im weary lol

Comment: Hey buddy,/.,... looking at your query, and just now implementing it, did you notice that in your `coalesce y` statements, that for all 3 tables, the second column IS DIFFERENT!  `id_y, id_z, & id_a`...therefore, this query WILL NOT WORk

Comment: a slight modification to the the second coalesce statement did the trick....query is now working.  sorry for the late accept